# Reset Filter to initial filter value in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I have a MapLibre / Mapbox GL JS web application, where I load vector tile data for which I apply a style using a local JSON file. For the different layers I use filters like that:

```
"filter": [
    "all",
    ["==", "size", "large"]
  ]
```

Now I want the user to be able to further filter the data, e.g. only view those data that have a specific category. Applying a further filter works easily, by getting the existing filter and appending the new filter.

```
map.setFilter('layerID', ["all", ["==", "size", "large"], ["==", "category", "A"]]
```

But how can I reset the filter so that it matches the initial value (where already the two filters are applied)? I know that I can completely remove the filter doing

```
map.setFilter('layerID', null)
```

but then, also the filter for size large is gone.

**Is there a possibility to reset a filter to its initial value?**

One "workaround" I could think of is to get the filter onInit and store it. When resetting the filter, do not set to null but to the stored value. But I thought maybe there is a built in function that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of "initial value".

You can store the current filter state like this:

```
const filter = map.getFilter('layerID');
```

and reset it back to that value like this:

```
map.setFilter('layerID', filter);
```